# Why gstreamer tee element sometimes adds a long latency

Tags: gstreamer, latency

I'm have a gstreamer pipeline: udpsrc ! Tsparse ! Tsdemux ! Tee1 ! Parsebin ! Tee2 ! Queue ! Rtphpay ! Webrtcbin

Usually the first tee has only one src pad, the seconds tee has many.
How come the first tee adds way more latency than the second one? It basically does nothing.

How can I address this to lower the pipeline latency?

I have Used a gst trace to measure the latency of all the elements in the pipeline, and the first tee takes about 120ms, which is almost as the rtph264pay though it does nothing.
The second tee takes about 20ms